# Tridion deployer removes localized/parent files

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We are facing weird behaviour during publishing pages in Tridion.

We have English pages in 050 publication and same pages are localized in 060 publication. Let's take a sample page **accounts** (**tcm:120-1234**) in English publication and same localized page (**tcm:125-1234**) in Spanish Publication.

When we publish English page, *accounts*, it gets published successfully but local deployer removes the its spanish page (**tcm:125-1234**). When we publish Spanish page, it removes its English page (**tcm:120-1234**).

We have verified the deployer side and confirmed that other file gets removed from the server itself.

Please refer below the deployer log for instructing to remove the page. But we are not sure why it removes other publication file. Is it becasue of the same page item id? I think it shouldn't, since it is localized.

**DEBUG FSEntityManager - Removing pagemeta/pageurl/business/accounts.content in transaction tcm:0-754-66560.**

We understand from this log that this been instructed from deployer but not sure how & why it was requested. We are analyzing what *FSEntityManager* class is doing.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Please specify your version of SDL Tridion, and include a copy of your cd_storage.xml (or cd_broker.xml) file, as this may be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the File System is used for storing content and metadata, the content of the Master or Child Publications will be over written.

To account for this, set explicit settings for metadata in cd_storage_conf.xml, to ensure that all metadata does not go to the same storage location, for example:

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
    <Root Path="c:\published\localFileSystem" />
</Storage>
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true">
    <Root Path="c:\published\localFileSystem\data" />
</Storage>

<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultFile" cached="false">       
        <!-- Query type mapping is replacement for Query gnenerator. If there was query generator defined in a Broker configuration then  Query type mapping should be binded to default DB. -->
        <Item typeMapping="Query" storageId="defaultdb"/>

        <Item typeMapping="PageMeta" cached="true" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>
        <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentationMeta" cached="true" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>
        <Item typeMapping="ComponentMeta" cached="true" storageId="defaultDataFile"/>

</ItemTypes>
```

Answer (score 5):

That looks like both publications share the same webroot. Check your storage Conf and publication path properties.

Comment: Thanks Nuno & Chris for your input. Since we are using File System in Local Deployer  and DB in Master Deployer, metadata of Master/Child publications was overwritten. SDL Support helped us to resolve the problem. It's a configuration change in the deployer.

Comment: You should put the solution as an answer and accept it so it can help others.